# vtkWindowToImageFilter causing memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, vtk

I have written a small tool that creates screenshots of a number of STLs from different camera angles. `vtkWindowToImageFilter`converts the contents of the `vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow`to an image, after which `vtkPngWriter`is used to write the image to a file.

I have noticed that the memory usage of the tool keeps rising with every screenshot it makes. After some debugging, I found out that the line of code that causes a rise in memory that is not freed at some point is

```
windowToImageFilter.Update();
```

Does anyone know if I should free some memory used by `vtkWindowToImageFilter`?

This is the complete function that creates the screenshots from different camera angles, for one set of STLs.

```
public void makeImage(vtkRenderWindow window, vtkRenderer renderer, string filePrefix="")
{
    if (_parts.Count == 0)
       return;

    // Make cameras
    Cameras cameras = new Cameras(_axial, _coronal, _sagittal, _parts[0].center, _parts[0].zoomfactor);

    // VTK
    // Setup vtkPNGwriter
    vtkPNGWriter writer = vtkPNGWriter.New();
    // Setup window to image filter
    vtkWindowToImageFilter windowToImageFilter = vtkWindowToImageFilter.New();
    windowToImageFilter.SetInput(window);
    windowToImageFilter.SetMagnification(2); // set the resolution of the output image (3 times the current resolution of vtk render window)

    foreach (string camName in cameraNames)
    {
       vtkCamera cam = cameras.getCameraByName(camName);
       if (cam == null)
           continue;

       // Skip already created screenshots
       if (File.Exists(getFilename(camName,filePrefix)))
            continue;

       // Clear renderer
       renderer.RemoveAllViewProps();

       // Show parts
       this.show(renderer);

       // Set camera
       renderer.SetActiveCamera(cam);
       renderer.GetActiveCamera().SetClippingRange(1.0, 1000);
       window.Render();

       // Update window to image filter
       windowToImageFilter.Update();

       // Write to png
       writer.SetFileName(tempFile);
       writer.SetInput(windowToImageFilter.GetOutput());
       writer.Write();

       // Crop png image
       Bitmap img = new Bitmap(tempFile);
       Bitmap imgCrop = cropImage(img);
       imgCrop.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
       imgCrop.Save(getFilename(camName,filePrefix));

       // Dispose images (necessary to avoid memory filling)
       img.Dispose();
       imgCrop.Dispose();

       // Delete temporary file
       File.Delete(tempFile);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I noticed that the tool created several screenshots from the same camera viewpoint (caused by the SetInput method of `vtkWindowToImageFilter` being used outside the loop), I rewrote the code to create a `vtkWindowToImageFilter` and a `vtkPngWriter` inside the `foreach` loop. This allowed me to dispose them after they have been used, freeing up the memory.

Note that in the previous version of the code, I also tried to dispose the `vtkWindowToImageFilter` and `vtkPngWriter` right after the end of the loop, but this did not seem to free up any memory. Unfortunately, it is not clear to me why this would not work.

The current version of the code looks like this and does not cause a memory leak, as stated before.

```
public void makeImage(vtkRenderWindow window, vtkRenderer renderer,string filePrefix="")
{
    if (_parts.Count == 0)
        return;

    // Make cameras
    Cameras cameras = new Cameras(_axial, _coronal, _sagittal, _parts[0].center, _parts[0].zoomfactor);

    foreach (string camName in cameraNames)
    {
        vtkCamera cam = cameras.getCameraByName(camName);
        if (cam == null)
            continue;
        // Skip already created screenshots
        if (File.Exists(getFilename(camName, filePrefix)))
            continue;

        // Clear renderer
        renderer.RemoveAllViewProps();

        // Show parts
        this.show(renderer);

        // Set camera
        renderer.SetActiveCamera(cam);
        renderer.GetActiveCamera().SetClippingRange(1.0, 1000);
        window.Render();

        // Update window to image filter
        vtkWindowToImageFilter windowToImageFilter = vtkWindowToImageFilter.New();
        windowToImageFilter.SetMagnification(4); // set the resolution of the output image (3 times the current resolution of vtk render window)
        windowToImageFilter.SetInput(window);

        // Write to png
        vtkPNGWriter writer = vtkPNGWriter.New();
        writer.SetInputConnection(windowToImageFilter.GetOutputPort());
        writer.SetFileName(tempFile);
        writer.Write();

        // Dispose pipeline parts
        windowToImageFilter.Dispose();
        writer.Dispose();

        // Crop png image
        Bitmap img = new Bitmap(tempFile);
        Bitmap imgCrop = cropImage(img, squareImages);
        imgCrop.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
        imgCrop.Save(getFilename(camName,filePrefix));

        // Dispose images (necessary to avoid memory filling)
        img.Dispose();
        imgCrop.Dispose();

        // Delete temporary file
        File.Delete(tempFile);
    }
}
```